# Porting .NET CF 3.5 to 3.9 - What about SQLCE?

Tags: sql-server-ce, .net-cf-3.5, windows-embedded-compact

I'm planning to migrate a managed Windows CE 6 application to run on Windows Embedded Compact 2013. Currently, the app is based on .net CF 3.5 and as you know, WEC2013 includes .net CF 3.9

My app uses a file based database (.sdf) and now I've read that .net CF 3.9 no longer supports SQL Server Compact.

Does this really mean that I have to switch over to SQLite or can I still include SQLCE in my cab file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server Compact is no longer supported with Embedded Compact 2013, you can use sqlite instead https://cesqlite2013.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look into it. I guess sqlite can't handle sdf files, can it? ;-)

Comment: Nope, but you can use my SQL CE Toolbox and the sqlite3 command line tool to convert a SQLCE database to SQLite